# Сменяемый текст onClick

Tags: java, android, textview

Не понимаю как сделать сменяемый текст при нажатии, который будет повторяться по кругу.
Хочу сделать следующее:
Нажатие - `textView` меняется на "Привет!"
Нажатие - `textView` меняется на "Как дела?"
Нажатие - `textView` меняется на "Пока."
И так по кругу.

Все нажатия происходят на одной кнопке.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте реализовать через список:

Kotlin:

```
val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("Привет!", "Как дела?", "Пока")
var position = 0
button.setOnClickListener {
    textView.text = list[position]
    position++
    if (position >= list.size) {
        position = 0
    }
}
```

Java:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Привет!");
list.add("Как дела?");
list.add("Пока");
int position = 0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText = list.get(position);
        position++;
        if (position >= list.size()) {
            position = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Только лучше `if (position >= list.size())` - чтобы не получать ошибок каждый раз, когда захочется расширить словарный запас :)

Comment: @woesss да, пожалуй так ему будет проще, изменил ответ

Comment: Вроде бы понятно как реализовать, но не могу получить позицию из списка и прибавить к ней индекс.

Comment: Мужики, переведите пожалуйста код в Java, я вообще не понимаю как позицию элемента из списка получить)

Comment: @TrapManny Я добавил код, но не тестировал его. Элемент получается методом .get(index) или если нужен индекс, то метод .indexOf(element)

Comment: Бро, чутка переделал код, но всё работает. Спасибо, весь день провозился!

Пытался через .get(index) и . indexOf(), все равно выдавало последний элемент из списка, что бы я не делал.